# python3: symbol lookup error: python3: undefined symbol: _Py_LegacyLocaleDetected when using slurm

Tags: python, pytorch, slurm

Good morning, i´ve encountered the following error message `python3: symbol lookup error: python3: undefined symbol: _Py_LegacyLocaleDetected` when trying to run a script using slurm.

the script is a deep learning task using pytorch, torchvision, tensorboard and configparser.
tensorboard and configparser are installed in the venv that is used, pytorch is loaded as module from the server `module load PyTorch/1.1.0-foss-2019a-Python-3.6.8`
I think the error has to do something with versioning, but i haven´t found anything useful on google.
any ideas how to fix it?

Here´s a list of all loaded modules:
Currently Loaded Modules:

1. binutils/.2.31.1-GCCcore-8.2.0              (H)
2. zlib/.1.2.11-GCCcore-8.2.0                  (H)
3. numactl/.2.0.12-GCCcore-8.2.0               (H)
4. XZ/.5.2.4-GCCcore-8.2.0                     (H)
5. libxml2/.2.9.8-GCCcore-8.2.0                (H)
6. libpciaccess/.0.14-GCCcore-8.2.0            (H)
7. hwloc/.1.11.11-GCCcore-8.2.0                (H)
8. OpenMPI/.3.1.3-GCC-8.2.0-2.31.1             (H)
9. OpenBLAS/.0.3.5-GCC-8.2.0-2.31.1            (H)
10. GCC/8.2.0-2.31.1
11. gompi/.2019a                                (H)
12. FFTW/.3.3.8-gompi-2019a                     (H)
13. ScaLAPACK/.2.0.2-gompi-2019a-OpenBLAS-0.3.5 (H)
14. foss/2019a
15. StdEnv
16. GCCcore/.8.2.0                              (H)
17. bzip2/.1.0.6-GCCcore-8.2.0                  (H)
18. ncurses/.6.1-GCCcore-8.2.0                  (H)
19. libreadline/.7.0-GCCcore-8.2.0              (H)
20. Tcl/8.6.9-GCCcore-8.2.0
21. SQLite/.3.27.2-GCCcore-8.2.0                (H)
22. GMP/.6.1.2-GCCcore-8.2.0                    (H)
23. libffi/.3.2.1-GCCcore-8.2.0                 (H)
24. expat/.2.2.6-GCCcore-8.2.0                  (H)
25. libpng/.1.6.36-GCCcore-8.2.0                (H)
26. freetype/.2.10.0-GCCcore-8.2.0              (H)
27. util-linux/.2.33.1-GCCcore-8.2.0            (H)
28. fontconfig/.2.13.1-GCCcore-8.2.0            (H)
29. X11/.20180604-GCCcore-8.2.0                 (H)
30. Tk/8.6.9-GCCcore-8.2.0
31. Python/3.6.8-foss-2019a
32. CUDA/10.1.105
33. cuDNN/7.5.0-CUDA-10.1.105
34. magma/.2.4.0-foss-2019a-CUDA-10.1.105       (H)
35. libyaml/.0.2.2-GCCcore-8.2.0                (H)
36. PyYAML/.5.1-foss-2019a-Python-3.6.8         (H)
37. NASM/.2.14.02-GCCcore-8.2.0                 (H)
38. x264/.20181203-GCCcore-8.2.0                (H)
39. LAME/.3.100-GCCcore-8.2.0                   (H)
40. x265/.3.0-GCCcore-8.2.0                     (H)
41. FriBidi/.1.0.5-GCCcore-8.2.0                (H)
42. FFmpeg/4.1.3-foss-2019a
43. libjpeg-turbo/.2.0.2-GCCcore-8.2.0          (H)
44. LibTIFF/.4.0.10-GCCcore-8.2.0               (H)
45. JasPer/.2.0.16-GCCcore-8.2.0                (H)
46. Java/1.8.0_202
47. ant/.1.10.5-Java-1.8                        (H)
48. gettext/.0.19.8.1-GCCcore-8.2.0             (H)
49. PCRE/.8.42-GCCcore-8.2.0                    (H)
50. GLib/.2.54.3-GCCcore-8.2.0                  (H)
51. ATK/.2.28.1-foss-2019a                      (H)
52. Gdk-Pixbuf/.2.36.12-foss-2019a              (H)
53. pixman/.0.38.0-GCCcore-8.2.0                (H)
54. cairo/.1.16.0-GCCcore-8.2.0                 (H)
55. HarfBuzz/.2.2.0-foss-2019a                  (H)
56. Pango/.1.42.4-foss-2019a                    (H)
57. GTK+/.2.24.32-foss-2019a                    (H)
58. OpenCV/4.0.1-foss-2019a-Python-3.6.8
59. NCCL/.2.4.2-CUDA-10.1.105                   (H)
60. PyTorch/1.1.0-foss-2019a-Python-3.6.8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symbol lookup error in /usr/bin/python3 "\_Py\_CoerceLegacyLocale" in new Fedora 27](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47462386/symbol-lookup-error-in-usr-bin-python3-py-coercelegacylocale-in-new-fedora-2)